# Прокрутка вверх

Tags: javascript, html, скрипт, прокрутка

Как сделать прокрутку к верху страницы при открытии каждого нового элемента? Не используя якоря и гиперссылки. Т.е ткнул на кнопку, открылся новый экранчик, автоматом прокручиваем страницу наверх. `document.documentElement.scrollTop` не сработал (совсем)

Comment: window.scrollTo(pageX,pageY) пробовали?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`window.scrollBy(x, y)` - прокручивает страницу к указанной координате относительно всего документа.

Например `window.scrollBy(0, 0)` на самый вверх документа.

`window.scrollTo(x, y)` - прокручивает страницу на указанную координату относительно всего документа.

Например `window.scrollTo(0, -200)` вверх на 200px.